# How to catch exceptions with phpspec2

Tags: exception, phpspec

I'm trying to catch exceptions with my spec but i can't make it works. This is my code:

```
$this->edit('updated comment', $comment, $user)
    ->shouldReturnAnInstanceOf('\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\AccessDeniedHttpException');
```

What i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [documentation](http://www.phpspec.net/docs/introduction.html#matchers), you can do something like this using `Matcher` for testing exceptions:

```
$this
   ->shouldThrow('Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\AccessDeniedHttpException')
   ->during('edit', array('updated comment', $comment, $user));
```

You can also take a look into [cookbook](https://github.com/phpspec/phpspec/blob/master/docs/cookbook/matchers.rst#throw-matcher) which is in phpspec repository on Github.